# How to check a session variable in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, session-variables

i am working on a asp.net(with c#) web application and here i have problem.

That i have a customer page(customer.aspx) and in this page a user can fill it's information & user can also update if it's already a regsitered user.

So whenver this page loads i check that a user is logged in or not using a session variable and if that session variable is set then user can update his/her information and here is the code of checking at customer.aspx

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["customerID"] != null)
            {
               //here is my code
            }

        }
```

but the issue is if my user click on logout then all goes fine but if user just press the back button of my browser(IE 7.0) then user is allowded to update his/her infomation and this should not happen. So please tell me solution for this problem.

my logout.aspx code is here :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
```

so please suggest  me solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the Cache

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1)); 
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

[this link may help you](http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/articles/back-button-issue-after-logout-in-asp.net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It more than likely is the browser caching the page, rather than the page reloading.

Make sure that caching is turned off and for security measures check the session state when loading the page and redirect them if it isn't filled.

```
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "max-stale=0"); // HTTP 1.1  
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1  
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "pre-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1  
        Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1  
        Response.AppendHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=993"); // HTTP 1.1  
        Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Comment: thanks adam as on my customer.aspx page i am checking on page_load and redeirect them if they are not logged in and that's working fine but the problem is with browser back button that even after log out if user press back button then all infomation is shown of the previous logged in user.

Comment: As suggested you need to clear the cache. I have updated my answer to show you some code to stop caching.